# Vancouver style citation and multiple sentences

Tags: citations, citation-style

I use a numbered citation style in my research paper. How should I use a citation when I have multiple sentences from the same source?

E.g. for one sentence it’s easy:

> My apple is red (1).

However, for many sentences:

> My apple is red (1). Yours is green. And your pet’s. (2.)

Is it right to put a dot after the number two to indicate that the citation applies to every sentence after previous citation?

Comment: This kind of question ("it is right?") has no real answer; it comes down to a combination of personal preference, citation style, and the style of the journal where the paper will be published.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain whether or not you are technically current about the meaning of a dot after a citation in this particular style.

What I *am* certain about, however, is that any such convention is extremely subtle and easy for a reader to misinterpret, both because it's not standard in most styles and because a period is not particularly visually salient.  I would thus strongly suggest using other means, such as how you actually construct your prose, to signal more clearly to the reader which facts belong together as a cited bundle.